# Esta me retornando um numero arredondado e eu nao quero quero numero ex 1.99 e nao 1.00 ou 2.00

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub txtPricePerQty_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPricePerQty.TextChanged
        Dim i As Double = 0
        i = CDbl(Val(txtQty.Text) * Val(txtPricePerQty.Text))
        i = Math.Round(i, 2)
        txtTotalAmount.Text = i
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, creio que o que esteja causando o arredondamento é o "Val()" pois ele esta convertendo um string em um valor numérico inteiro.

Comment: e oque tenho que fazer?

Comment: Aconcelho receber os valores que estão vindo do campo em variaveis compativeis com o tipo de dado que você quer que seja calculado,  como o proprio double, após isso faça os calculos com base nas variaveis, debuga antes para ver se os valores estão corretos(debug.print).

Comment: mas as variaveis estao todas como double

Answer (score 0):

dim Qty as double = Val(txtQty.Text)
dim PricePerQty as double = Val(txtPricePerQty.Text)

i = CDbl(Qty  * PricePerQty)

Comment: obrigado abraço